# Split and aggregating results without a loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where I would like to group the results by name and type, and if my scenario has an "up" or "down", report these as separate columns line (where the "value" is the minimum of the these two results).

Using string split and loops, I can sort through the columns, split the string, replace with N/A etc but this feels incredibly clumsy.

Can anyone suggest a better way to produce the preferred output that doesn't use a loop?

My input looks like:

```
input = structure(list(Name = c("Alice", "Alice ", "Tim", "Tim", "Greg", 
"Greg"), Value = c("-5", "6", "5", "-2", "5", "7"), Type = c("Sales", 
"Sales", "Returns", "Returns", "Promo", "Promo"), Scenario = c("Down", 
"Up", "Down_RED_One", "Up_RED_One", "BLUE", "YELLOW")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And my preferred output is:

```
output = structure(list(Name = c("Alice", "Tim", "Greg", "Greg"), Value = c("-5", 
"-2", "5", "7"), Type = c("Sales", "Returns", "Promo", "Promo"
), Scenario = c("N/A", "RED_One", "BLUE", "YELLOW"), Up = c("6", 
"-2", "N/A", "N/A"), Down = c("-5", "5", "N/A", "N/A")), row.names = 1:4, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do some initial transformation to extract `"Up"` and `"Down"` and get your minima, then `tidyr::pivot_wider()`:

```
library(dplyr)   # >= v1.1.0
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

input %>%
  mutate(
    UpDown = str_extract(Scenario, "Up|Down"),
    Scenario = na_if(str_remove(Scenario, "_?(Up|Down)_?"), ""),
    ValuePivot = Value
  ) %>%
  mutate(Value = min(Value), .by = c(Name, Scenario)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = UpDown, values_from = ValuePivot) %>%
  select(!`NA`)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  Name  Value Type    Scenario Down  Up   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>
1 Alice -5    Sales   <NA>     -5    6    
2 Tim   -2    Returns RED_One  5     -2   
3 Greg  5     Promo   BLUE     <NA>  <NA> 
4 Greg  7     Promo   YELLOW   <NA>  <NA>
```

Note, one value of `"Alice"` had a trailing space, which I assumed was an error and removed.

Answer (score 1):

My answer works, but I can't help but think there has to be a better way.

I have added several comments to explain what does what and why. If you have any questions, let me know.

```
library(tidyverse)

input %>% 
  separate_wider_regex(Scenario,                                # separate up and down
                       patterns = c(Up = "Up|Down|", Scenario = ".*"),
                       too_few = "error") %>% 
  mutate(Scenario = trimws(Scenario, which = "left", whitespace = "_"), # drop leading _
         Name = trimws(Name, "both"),       # drop whitespace causing mismatch
         Up = ifelse(Up == "", NA, Up)) %>% # change blank strings to NA for pivot
  pivot_wider(values_from = Value, names_from = Up)
# # A tibble: 4 × 6
#   Name  Type    Scenario  Down  Up    `NA` 
#   <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 Alice Sales   ""        -5    6     <NA> 
# 2 Tim   Returns "RED_One" 5     -2    <NA> 
# 3 Greg  Promo   "BLUE"    <NA>  <NA>  5    
# 4 Greg  Promo   "YELLOW"  <NA>  <NA>  7
```